# displaying field from different object in apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page that contains the following snippet:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable id="qliList" value="{!qliProdList}" var="qliProd" columns="3">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            {!qliProd.Name}
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!qliQuantity}">
                <apex:param name="qliID" value="{!qliProd.Id}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!delQLI}" rerender="qliList" value="Remove">
                <apex:param name="qliID" value="{!qliProd.Id}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I have the following relevant apex code:

```
public class MyController {
    public List<QuoteLineItem> qliList = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
    public MyController() {

        // some code that instantiates (but does not insert) quote line items 
        // and adds them to qliList. Code is omitted for brevity

    }

    public List<Product2> get QliProdList() {
        List<Product2> qliProdList = new List<Product2>();
        for (QuoteLineItem qli : qliList) {
            Product2 prod = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :qli.Product2Id]; 
            qliProdList.add(prod);
        }
        return qliProdList;
    }

    public Double getQLIQuantity() {
        String qliID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('qliID');
        system.debug('trying to get QLI quantity for ID: ' + qliID);
        for (QuoteLineItem qli : qliList) {
            if (qli.Product2Id == qliId) {
                return qli.Quantity;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void delQLI() {
        String qliID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('qliID');
        for (Integer i = qliList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (qliList[i].Product2Id == qliID) {
                qliList.remove(i);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The "remove" commandButton works beautifully. However, I can't get the quote line item's quantity value in the apex:outPutText. qliID comes back null. I did some googling and apparently people are saying that I need to make a wrapper class for my qliProdList. However, I tried all the examples I found on stack overflow and none of them work. I managed to make a qliProdListWrapper class and added a "public List qliProdList {get; set;}" that doesn't cause the entire vf page to stop working, but then my list just comes back empty.

In a nutshell, all I want is to be able to generate a list using apex:pageBlockTable of my quote line items where I can display the product name, quote line item quantity and have a commandbutton to remove them from the list. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out a way to make this work since the quote line item doesn't store the product's name - I have to fetch the product2 object instance for that using the quote line item's Product2Id field which is a major PITA, but I don't know any other way to get this data.

Please let me know if there's a clean way I can do this

P.S. the quote line items have NOT been inserted yet. This VF page is supposed to display a preview of them before insertion. They only exist as instances of QuoteLineItem(); in my apex controller and have not been inserted yet. There is no way to pull them up with a SOQL query since they would have to be inserted first for that to work.

So again, all I want is an apex:pageBlockTable that displays all the quote line items in my qliList, but I also need it to display product names, which are fields in the related Product2 object, not the quote line item object (hence why I had to write all that extra ugly code to generate qliProdList from the quote line item's product2Id).

Worst case scenario, I could create a formula field in the Quote Line Item object itself that gets the name from the associated Product2 record, but I'd rather do it in the apex controller if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a map of the products, you could display the name that way. Here's the relevant modifications.

## Controller

```
public class MyController {
    public List<QuoteLineItem> qliList { get; set; }
    // Contains products in the quote line items
    public Map<Id, Product2> products { get; set; }
    public MyController() {
        qliList = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
        products = new Map<Id, Product2>();
        // populate qliList ...
        // ... then ...
        Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(QuoteLineItem item: qliList) {
            productIds.add(item.Product2Id);
        }
        products.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :productIds]);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

## Page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="qliList" value="{!qliList}" var="qliProd" columns="3">
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!products[qliProd.Product2Id].Name}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" value="{!qliProd.Quantity}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!delQLI}" rerender="qliList" value="Remove">
            <apex:param name="qliID" value="{!qliProd.Id}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

---

Note: When using this technique, make certain that there is a key for each "Product2Id" that is in the map, otherwise you'll get an unrecoverable error regarding a missing key.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to put my products in a map but I'm getting an "Attempt to de-reference null object" error. I'm running a SOQL query to get the Product2 object for each Product2ID in my qliList, then calling products.put(qli.Product2ID, theproduct); in the controller. The error occurs on the first attempt to call products.put()

Comment: Hi, yeah I just figured that out. I was able to get rid of the error by instantiating it instead of doing public Map<Id, Product2> products {get; set;}. I also had the same issue when trying to do public List<QuoteLineItem> qliList { get; set; } as in your example. I changed that back to public List<QuoteLineItem> qliList = new List<QuoteLineItem>(); as well. Unfortunately now the product names are coming up blank in my visualforce page

Comment: Aha! I just needed to add a getter method for the map, its working now. Thank you for the help! I'll try to refactor this so I'm not running tons of SOQL queries in a loop as per your last suggestion

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Do you know how I can add all the products to the map after generating my qliList? I'm not sure how to do that without looping over qliList and running a SOQL query for each quotelineitem

Comment: @ag415 `Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>(); for(QuoteLineItem item: ...) {productIds.add(item.Product2Id); } products = new Map<Id, Product2>([SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :productIds]);`

Comment: thanks. That did the trick. I tried doing public List<QuoteLineItem> qliList {get; set;} and public Map<Id, Product2> products {get; set;} outside my controller method and then instantiating them inside the controller method, but I wasn't able to get them to display on the VF page even with getter methods for them. They only seem to display if I instantiate them first outside the controller method.

Comment: Actually that issue only seems to affect the qliList. I can do public Map<Id, Product2> products {get; set;}  outside the controller method and then instantiate it inside the method which works fine, but if I do public List<QuoteLineItem> qliList {get; set;} outside the method and then List<QuoteLineItem> qliList = new List<QuoteLineItem>(); inside the method, it doesn't render on the VF page, even with a getqliList() method

Comment: @ag415 I've edited this code to hopefully give some clarity to what I'm trying to say. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, I see what I was doing wrong now. I was prepending my assignments with the object type List<QuoteLineItem>, Map<Id, Product2> in my constructor method. It works fine now as per your updated example if I don't include those type prefixes in the assignments. Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.